# cakephp pagination GET params

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have problem with cakephp pagination if i pass GET url

everything work fine if i don't add use GET param

like this
page #2

> domain/imsystem/admin/remuneration_points/#admin/remuneration_points/index/page:2

but when i add GET param the like become this

> domain/imsystem/admin/remuneration_points/#imsystem/admin/remuneration_points/index/page:2?Employee_name=&Employee_branch_id=1&Employee_departement_id=1

it come which extra 'imsystem', how to remove this?
for the $paginator->options($opt);

this is for normal url

> $opt['url'] =
>   '#admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/'.str_replace($this->params['prefix'].'_',
>   '', $this->params['action']);

if with GET param

i set

> $opt['url'] = $args;

which is array

> Array (
>       [url] => Array
>           (
>               [?] => Employee_name=&akhir_tanggal=&Employee_branch_id=1&Employee_departement_id=1
>           )
>
> )

Comment: Please read it http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: i have read it, still don't got it, can you give more details?

Comment: don't get your Query that why i share you link..

Comment: i have add extra field, pls read it

Comment: question is not clear.....update your question with whole controller and view..

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your html urls

they proubly have something like `<a href ="#imsystem/">`

Answer (score 0):

It's not apparent where the second `imsystem` comes from as the code which is apparently responsible for defining that is in the question. However:

### That won't work

Unless you're using js (in which case - you don't really need js for defining the pagination links) - if you have a url of the form:

> example.com/imsystem/admin/remuneration_points/#admin/remuneration_points/index/page:2

The only thing that is seen server side is:

> example.com/imsystem/admin/remuneration_points/

The url fragment only exists on the browser, which means that irrespective of the url, it will be page one with default sort/limit/order.

It's probably a good idea to [setup pagination using get parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters), which will "just work" and go from there.